# Converting finalBufferData into img url to display

Tags: json, android-studio, android-asynctask, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to extract several images url constructed from parts of a JSON to be displayed.

I was able to retrieve the JSON and then construct several url from the JSON displaying it as a text on the screen ( String ).

at the end of the AsyncTask i used the Universal Image Loader, to display a single pic, in case the JSON contain information of a single pic, but the problem is whnen construct several url from the JSON :

```
finalBufferData.append("http://res.cloudinary.com/CLOUD_NAME/" + fileType +
                        "/upload/v" + version + "/" + publicID + "." + format + "/n");
```

it create a string of address just in separate lines ( if displayed in a textView), but bening passed to UIL it is not acceptable.

So i am not sure how to do this, since i am trying to have an image view within a listView in a linearway or differently maybe, to display several images, depending on the JSON information .

Any suggestion on how to do this will be great .

My AsyncTask code it;

```
 public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("resources");

            StringBuffer finalBufferData = new StringBuffer();

            for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String publicID = finalObject.getString("public_id");
                String version = finalObject.getString("version");
                String format = finalObject.getString("format");
                finalBufferData.append("http://res.cloudinary.com/CLOUD_NAME/" + fileType +
                        "/upload/v" + version + "/" + publicID + "." + format);

            }
            return finalBufferData.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();


            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(result, imageViewDisplayUp);

        //imagesList.setText(result);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way around it, by adding another String which is not in the JSON but get created from other JASON strings.

Since the public_id, version, and format are in the JSON downloaded from Cloudinary and needed to build the right address for the images to be passed into the ImageLoader, and i couldnt not find another way to retrieve a list of images urls uploaded by the user with a specific tag to Cloudinary, without using the admin api which require writing api_secret in the program, i ended up doing the following;

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<upImgModels> > {



    @Override
    protected List<upImgModels> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("resources");


            List<upImgModels> upImgList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                upImgModels upImgModels = new upImgModels();
                upImgModels.setPublic_id(finalObject.getString("public_id"));
                upImgModels.setVersion(finalObject.getString("version"));
                upImgModels.setFormat(finalObject.getString("format"));

                upImgModels.setAddress("http://res.cloudinary.com/we4x4/" + fileType
                        + "/upload/v" + finalObject.getString("version") + "/"
                        + finalObject.getString("public_id") + "." +
                        finalObject.getString("format"));

                upImgList.add(upImgModels);
            }
            return upImgList;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();


            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<upImgModels> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        upImgAdapter adapter = new upImgAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
        listViewUpload.setAdapter(adapter);
        //imagesList.setText(result);
    }

}


public class upImgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public List<upImgModels> upImgModelsList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public upImgAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<upImgModels> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        upImgModelsList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ImageView imageViewDisplay;
        imageViewDisplay = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDisplay);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(upImgModelsList.get(position).getAddress(), imageViewDisplay);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

I hope someone could suggest a better way to do this if it is possible, which i am sure that is the case.